# Django rest framework: nested serializers a proper way to update?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

I pretty new to django and django rest framework... I still learning so excuse me if I am asking silly question... I am sorry in advance...

That said !

Here are the models that I am working on:

```
class Targets(models.Model):
    first_name = models.TextField()
    last_name = models.TextField()
    email = models.TextField()
    position = models.TextField()

class Groups(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_id')
    name = models.TextField(unique=True, null=False)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    targets = models.ManyToManyField(Targets)
```

Groups extends the core User models
So a User can have multiple Groups.
Groups have multiple Targets
Targets can be part of multiple Groups

Here are the endpoints:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('groups/', GroupsAPIView.as_view()),
    path('groups/<int:pk>/', GroupsIDAPIView.as_view())
]
```

Here are the serializers:

```
class GroupsIDSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    targets = TargetsSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Groups
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'modified_date', 'user_id', 'targets', )

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        targets = validated_data.pop('targets')
        group = Groups.objects.filter(id=instance.id).first()
        Groups.objects.filter(id=instance.id).update(**validated_data)
        group.targets.clear()
        for target in targets:
            obj, created = Targets.objects.get_or_create(**target)
            group.targets.add(obj)
        return Groups.objects.filter(id=instance.id)

class TargetsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Targets
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'position', )
```

Here are the views:

```
class GroupsIDAPIView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Groups.objects.all()
    serializer_class = groups.GroupsIDSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(GroupsIDAPIView, self).get_queryset()
        queryset = queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return queryset
```

Here are the behavior of an API that I want to build:

```
PUT (url/groups/<int:pk>): Modify the specific group with all the targets for the connected user

{
    "name":"changed",
    "targets":[
        {
            "first_name": "changed",
            "last_name": "a",
            "email": "a@a.fr",
            "position":"a"
        }
    ]
}

Response =>
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "changed",
    "modified_date": "new date",
    "user_id": 1,
    "targets": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "first_name": "changed",
            "last_name": "a",
            "email": "a@a.fr",
            "position": "a"
        }
    ]
}
```

With everything that I said... Here are the issues:

1) I still have issues with the `PUT (url/groups/<int:pk>)`. Which is still not working... Don't know how to update only the targets of that said group.
I got the following error: `Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field 'name' on serializer 'GroupsIDSerializer'.`

2) Proper way to handle errors and rollback ? I think the solution is to use Atomic transactions ? But I am not sure ? If you are willing to give an example, I will be grateful...

3) I am not sure if what I am doing is correct actually... I am willing to get any feedback on all of this. Since the rest of the project is pretty similar.

4) Thank you again !

Regards,

Comment: why are you using a through table if you're not adding any data? By default, if you create a many-to-many relationship (without through), Django will handle the join table for you behind the scenes so you don't have to create the rows yourself.

Comment: Also note that the QuerySet method `.update()` returns an integer, the number of rows that were updated. So you can't assign it to `group` and then return `group` in your `update` method because it means you're returning an int, hence your error.

Comment: Thank you for your insight... Going to read this again !

Comment: Updated the issue. As you said it is handled by django ! That's amazing !

Comment: As I told you: `group = Groups.objects.filter(id=instance.id).update(**validated_data)` assigns the number of rows updated to `group` (the result of `.update(**validated_data)`)

Comment: Updated the issue. Not sure if that's the way to proceed now.

Comment: `return group` instead of returning a QuerySet.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Seems like I figure this out.